# Counting number of words from void method in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am having problem in this program that i have. i want to be able to print the random words from the void Spoken() method and also to be able to return the number of words that are counted using the Main() method.

```
 static void Main ()
  {
    Spoken ();
    string sentence = Spoken ();
      string[] words = sentence.Split (' ');
      Console.WriteLine("Words counted: " + words.Length);
  }
  static void Spoken ()
  {
    var wordss = new string[]{
      "\nfine day\n",
      "\nnight time\n",
      "\nexclusive place to unpack\n",
      "\ndoing better at clicking\n",
      "\nkilling time?\n",
    };
    var ran = new Random ();
    var pc = ran.Next (words.Length);
    Console.WriteLine (words[pc]);
  }
```

> sample output:
>
> exclusive place to unpack
>
> Words counted: 4

what should i do? and is there a way? any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Make it return a string is the simplest solution

Comment: Returning a string would indeed be the simplest solution. However, you could store the latest line you printed in a static variable and access it in your Main method.

Comment: I removed the "recursion" tag because there is no recursion in code, nor did you ask for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method declaration to return `string` and then return `words[pc]` from the method.

Or if you want to return only the count if words then keep the `Console.WriteLine` in the Spoken method and just return the array length fr the method.

If only printing to the console is the only motive then you can keep the method as returning `void` and print inside the method only.

And if the intention is to just print the words and count then you can avoid `Split`. You can just run a for loop and check for the `IsWhiteSpace` and keep on incrementing counter value.